# to change the image property of the imageview through code

Tags: android, imageview

I want to put change the image (source) of the imageview in android UI..
could not do it using the code 
my code is as follows :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);

    Timer Tim=new Timer();
    Tim.schedule(new TimerTask() 
    {   @Override
        public void run() 
        {    runthread();   }
    },1000,1000);
}
public void runthread () {
    int x=0;
    if(x==0)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd);    }
    if(x==1)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd1);   }
    if(x==2)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd22);  }
    if(x==3)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd3);   }
    if(x==4)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd4);   }
    if(x==5)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd5);   }
    if(x==6)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd6);   }
    if(x==7)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd7);   }
    if(x==8)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd8);   }
    if(x==9)
    {   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd9);   }
    x=x+1;
    if(x==10){x=1;}

}
```

i want to keep counting from 0 to 10 in my UI but this code is not working properly can anyone tel me the problem so that i can modify it so that i can proceed.
thanks in advance

Comment: what type of issue are u facing explain clearly?

Comment: x is always 0 ... so iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd);  will always run

Comment: initialize ur variable x outside the thread

Comment: I initialised it outside also but 
This in nor working dude/..:(

Comment: I initialised it outside also but This in nor working dude/..:(
@Deepzz

Answer (score 0):

initialize your `x` variable to global meaning initialize it outside your method
,don't keep on initializing it inside your `runthread()` method , you will always get x=0 for that.

and in your last condition,change it to this

`if(x==10){x=0;}`

and also

place your timer in onWindowsFocusChanged() override that method

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   Timer Tim=new Timer();
   Tim.schedule(new TimerTask() 
   {   @Override
       public void run() 
       {    runthread();   }
    },1000,1000);
}
```

because onWindowsFocusChanged() signifies that your layout has been loaded properly, that's the time you can manipulate your Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

your are missing thing in your code and that is following

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));
```

so

```
 public void runthread () {
    int x=0;
    if(x==0)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));   }
    if(x==1)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image)); }
    if(x==2)
    {  iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));  }
    if(x==3)
    {    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));   }
    if(x==4)
    {    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));  }
    if(x==5)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));  }
    if(x==6)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));   }
    if(x==7)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));   }
    if(x==8)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));   }
    if(x==9)
    {   iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image));   }
    x=x+1;
    if(x==10){x=1;}
```

change image name and run the code it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use so many "if statment", its dirty code

2) your x variable must be global

3) Use this

```
private int mX=0;

public void runthread () {
    switch(mX){
        case 0: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd); break;
        case 1: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd1); break;
        case 2: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd2); break;
        case 3: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd3); break;
        case 4: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd4); break;
        case 5: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd5); break;
        case 6: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd6); break;
        case 7: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd7); break;
        case 8: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd8); break;
        case 9: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd9); break;
    }
    mX = (mX+1) %10;
}
```

UPDATED:

4) Also don't change UI on another thread (as noticed Simon). Can use this:

```
    Tim.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){    
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { runthread(); } });
        }
    },1000,1000);
```

Comment: sorry, its wrong, the last sentence shoud be %10 not %1. I change my answer

Comment: I changed that already still not working
 I declared this activity in menefest also but still it is showing "unfortunately app stopped"...:(

Comment: This code is working, as I tested. The problem might be on another side. Can you post the LogCat error?

Comment: @Scorpian You fail to use runOnUiThread (Runnable action). Use the method or use a Handler. You are getting an error because another thread is trying to manipulate the View which is bound only to the UI thread.

Comment: @Simon, you are really right. How could I missed that! Thanks

Comment: oooh yeh..
ill try that..:)

Comment: @Corbella No worries :) By the way I will post some code that is optimized for readability Scorpian may use.

Comment: i wrote this code now..:)

private void runthread()
 { runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() 
  { public void run() 
         {  switch(mX)
    {
case 0: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd); break;
case 1: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd1); break;
case 2: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd2); break;
case 3: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd3); break;
case 4: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd4); break;
...
...
case 8: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd8); break;
case 9: iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd9); break;}
   } 
          mX = (mX+1) %10;
         }
     }));
 }

Answer (score 0):

Based on code provided by Corbella this is for people that dislikes convenience methods as `runOnUiThread (Runnable action)`. Details at bottom.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int mX;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        updateImageContinuouslyWithTimer();
    }

    private void updateImageContinuouslyWithTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runthread();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }

    public void runthread() {
        switch (mX) {
        case 0:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd);
            break;
        case 1:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd5);
            break;
        case 6:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd6);
            break;
        case 7:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd7);
            break;
        case 8:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd8);
            break;
        case 9:
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lcd9);
            break;
        }

        mX = (mX + 1) % 10;
    }
}
```

It is proper named with lower case and underscores for the XML names and full length names for code. When you code you should aim for readability because not following convention will not only confuse you in the future but also other developers. Also prefix your member variables with m. This is how I suggest you do in the future.